# new column with values depending upon another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.2

---

I have a column "current stage" which can take values from 2 to 8.Based upon it my new column"possible stages" should have the values as 2 to current stage-1.
For example: if "current stage" is 5, possible stages should be 2,3,4 .(in sequence)

if ""current stage" is 6, possible stages should be 2,3,4,5 .(in sequence)

Comment: ah - just noticed - are you sure about 9.1?.. what's your `select version()`?..

Comment: btw - who knows where Ican test 9.1?.. sqlfiddle, db-fiddle and rextester don't haveone

Comment: its 8.2 ..sorry for the confusion